# How do I revert UIDevice.h back to the original version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fatal-error

I by accident edited UIDevice.h and proceeded to build my project but received the following error:

> fatal error: file '/Applications/Developer/Xcode5-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1EK79MZFJ723Q/UIKit.pcm' was built

I went into UIDevice.h and undid the changes I made, but this error persists. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to `touch` the file with the timestamp of other files in the same directory.

Comment: @Thilo - I'm not so familiar with that utility. If the timestamp of the other files is "July 26, 2013 6:26 PM", what should the `touch` command be?

Comment: Not using source control?

Comment: Try cleaning the project and then building it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by following @Thilo's suggestion of using `touch` to change the "UIDevice.h"'s access and modification date to the date of the other files in the directory. Since the modification date of all the other files was "July 26, 2013 6:26 PM", I just ran this command in Terminal:

```
touch -t '201307261826' UIDevice.h
```

And now my code works fine.

Comment: @Fred - It says I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow, so I'll do it then.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete folder "/Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1EK79MZFJ723Q/", clean & build. works for me.